# I want to delete multipale button on click onebyone not delete it all by one click

Tags: javascript, html, click, addeventlistener

I manage to delete button with  `<li>` element `class li_listItem"`. But my aim is to on click delete `<button>` itself and also `<li>` element with it. For now I  can only delete both elements only by clicking on it. Can you help me with it?

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('#shopping_list__items');

function DeleteButtonOnclick(e) {
  const trgt = e.target.closest('.deleteBtn, .li_listItem');
  if (trgt) trgt.remove();
}

ul.addEventListener("click", DeleteButtonOnclick);
```

```html
<ul id="shopping_list__items">
  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem" random="23">Notebook</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Jello</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Spinach</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Rice</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Birthday Cake</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Candles</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `this.parentNode.remove()` method to delete both the `<li>` element and the `<button>` element inside the  when the  element with the `deleteBtn` class style is applied is clicked.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteBtn");

var removeSelectedElement = function() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', removeSelectedElement, false);
}
```

```html
<ul id="shopping_list__items">
  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem" random="23">Notebook</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Jello</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Spinach</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Rice</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Birthday Cake</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <li class="li_listItem">Candles</li>
    <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes i can but my goal is only on button click, delete "button"" itself and also "li" Element ...but i don't want on click li to be deleted or deleted button , I want action only when you click on delete button.

Comment: @Abu_101 I updated this answer as I misunderstood the question. It does exactly what you want it to do. This code does the same job as the answer of DeFRaNDo.

Comment: Sorry No it doesn't,it deletes both element when you click entire flex container, It does not matter if you click on li element or button element it will delete it anyway. I want  on "button" click delete both, but not want to do any action when I am clicking on li element....I want on click delete 1) button itself and 2) li element only this way. I have other plans for li element.

Comment: @Abu_101 Ok now I get it `:)`. I edited the code.

Comment: thanks for help ,appreciate  :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your html structure the simplest way is to delete the parent of the button.
(I hope I didn't misunderstand what you want to do.)

```js
$(".deleteBtn").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shopping_list__items">
            <div class="flex">
              <li class="li_listItem" random="23">Notebook</li>
              <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex">
              <li class="li_listItem">Jello</li>
              <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex">
              <li class="li_listItem">Spinach</li>
              <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex">
              <li class="li_listItem">Rice</li>
              <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex">
              <li class="li_listItem">Birthday Cake</li>
              <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex">
              <li class="li_listItem">Candles</li>
              <button class="deleteBtn">Delete Button</button>
            </div>
          </ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted but without jquery,(I don't know jquery yet),But my task is to do it with Javascript only...

Comment: Simplest solution. <button class="deleteBtn" onclick="this.parentElement.remove();">Delete Button</button>

Comment: Yes but as i understand it only will delete button, not li element right?
Sorry Maybe I did not explain well what i wanted is here : 

I want on "button" click delete both elements, but not want to do any action when I am clicking on li element....I want on click delete 1) button itself and 2) li element only this way. I have other plans for li element.